# Какой знак препинания необходим в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак препинания необходим в данном случае?

*Уникальный талант (?) играть на нервах.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Уникальный **талант — играть** на нервах.*

> 2. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) или если один из главных членов выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — неопределенной формой глагола: <...> *Конечно, это большое **искусство — ждать*** (Соб.)...

Источник: [**Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92) (справочник Розенталя).